# Why doesn't the wildcard "?" work?

Tags: command-line, bash, wildcards

I'm learning to use the terminal on Ubuntu with WSL. Right now I'm practicing wildcards, but the `?` wildcard doesn't work for me.

As you can see, the `*` wildcard works but this one doesn't:

```
$ ls file*
file.html file.js file.txt
$ ls dot*
dot.txt dot1902.html dot2.txt
$ ls *.html
archivoPruebaClase.html dot1902.html file.html
$ ls dot?
ls: cannot access 'dot?': No such file or directory
$ ls index?
ls: cannot access 'index?': No such file or directory
```

Comment: what do you expect it to do differently?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it is working fine:

- A `*` will be replaced with any number of characters on the command line.
- A `?` will be replaced by exactly one character.

So for example `ls dot?.txt` will show `dot1.txt`, `dot2.txt`, etc., but it wouldn’t for example show `dot10.txt`.

Try `ls -a` to list all files/folders in that folder and you can then work out what should be listed with your wildcard use.

Comment: thank u. yep it took me like 3 hours but i figured out, yep just a noob mistake i was pretending to th terminal understood that i want the "filename" + ? but i completly ignore the extension, your answer just confirm my mistake, thank u a lot

Comment: @DanielSierra Easy mistake to make coming from Windows, which tends to "ignore" extensions in many cases.  Linux itself actually doesn't even "understand" extensions, for the most part -- It's simply part of the filename here.  It's us "humans" that tend to assign extensions on Linux for *our* organizational needs ;-).

Comment: @DanielSierra - that’s of course exactly what this site is for! It’s absolutely how to learn and how to use the site - have a go, try to work it out, if you get stuck ask. People here get irritated when people just post a question without trying but you did the opposite. I like answering these kinds of question because they make me check the advice I’m giving - and every now and then you get to learn something new in the process.